# Build error when update Flutter project to Gradle 4.1 on Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter

I have downloaded gradle v4.1 and I'm trying to update my Flutter app to use the new gradle version in Android Studio 3.0.1 
However, I get the errors below:

Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.

> Failed to transform file 'flutter-x86.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform
>   Transform output file Git/samplegradle/build/app/intermediates/flutter/flutter-x86.jar does not exist.

***EDIT*** - 
I followed this [example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Updating-Flutter-projects-to-Gradle-4.1-and-Android-Studio-Gradle-plugin-3.0.1) to update `gradle 3.0.1` manually, and it works for me, although it takes longer. I still haven't found a solution to update it using Android Studio.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening on me every time I do `flutter clean` on a particular project.

My hack is to run `(cd android/; ./gradlew flutterBuildX86Jar)`, which copies the missing file to the expected place.

Edit: Later I found out that the real problem was the order of the applied plugins. I added kotlin after creating project, and I need to apply kotlin plugin before flutter:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the steps outlined in [Updating Flutter projects to Gradle 4.1 and Android Studio Gradle plugin 3.0.1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Updating-Flutter-projects-to-Gradle-4.1-and-Android-Studio-Gradle-plugin-3.0.1)?

Also, you probably have to upgrade your flutter install to `0.0.20` or later, if you haven't done that already.

Comment: @liro yes, I have update `Flutter` to the latest version, and also follow the instructions on how to install it through Android Studio. However, it doesn't work for me, so I ended up update `gradle` manually (now it's working).

Comment: @grepLines Could you self-answer this question then, with the steps how to solve it, if you got it working? This could be helpful for people googling the error and landing here. :)